# Protected sheets - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have used the following function to protect a sheet

```
Sub sbProtectSheet()

    ActiveSheet.Protect "password", True, True

End Sub


Sub sbUnProtectSheet()

  ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
End Sub
```

There is a chart on this sheet that I want to unprotect while the rest of the sheet stays protected. I only seem to find that you can unlook a specfic range and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a macro that I have recorded just to see how do you get the Drawing Object available for selection:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= True
```

I am pretty sure that you would be able to fix it into your code.